# How can I perform a dynamic lazy component test in React?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using jest to perform unit tests, and I do not know how to test the following code

**javascript**

```
React.lazy(() => import(`path/to/dynamic/${icon}`));
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please note that this is an English-only site, and any questions and answers in anything other than English will be removed. Please edit you question and translate it into English, so that we can help you.

Comment: I have translated this from Spanish to English. Waiting on a peer review and it will come up properly.

Comment: Sorry by that, i thought that i was in spanish site